# Identifying identical "Feeling Lucky" searches

Tags: javascript, php, html, node.js

I'm trying to make a program within my website to test if the top search results for different searches are the same. For example, it should tell that the top search result for "twelve" and "12" are the same because the top result for both is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12_(number). Using google's feeling lucky search method they will both redirect to the same page, but I don't know how to get the redirected url or it's contents to determine whether or not they are the same.

I had been trying to do this by searching for both (12 and twelve) in iframes and then getting the URL that the iframe redirected to, but I couldn't get that to work due to them being in different domains. Is there anyway to do this?

Also, if there is a better way to do this then using feeling lucky searches that also works.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you want to do. What does it mean for "searches" to be "the same". What are you retrieving from these URLs? Maybe show some code and explain with an [edit] a bit more about what you want to achieve.

Comment: Tried to clarify what I was asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to security restrictions, your browser sandboxes iframes from different domains to prevent XSS. There are pretty extensive rules in place to prevent any activity like this, as an attacker could easily load up a sensitive website and scrape personal information from it. Even using GET requests in JavaScript will prevent you from gathering information from a cross-domain page.

---

### Node.js method

For scraping from the Google Search page, I would use an external tool, like [Node.js](https://nodejs.org) with [Nightwatch.js](http://nightwatchjs.org/), which can be used to easily automate web tasks like the one you're looking to accomplish.

Because you're simply trying to compare the resulting page of the "I'm Feeling Lucky" searches, you can use the Node.js [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) library to perform your requests, and compare the resulting data. Here's some working code:

```
var request = require("request");

var url1 = "https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=wikipediatwelve&btnI=I'm+Feeling+Lucky&aq=f&oq=";
var url2 = "https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=wikipedia&btnI=I'm+Feeling+Lucky&aq=f&oq=";

request(url1, function (error1, response1, body1) {
    request(url2, function (error2, response2, body2) {
        console.log(response1.request.uri.href); // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12_(number)
        console.log(response2.request.uri.href); // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
        if(response1.request.uri.href == response2.request.uri.href){
            console.log("Same page!");
        }else{
            console.log("Different page!");
        }
    });
});
```

If you don't have Node.js installed on your machine, you can play around with this code [here](https://runkit.com/ihatecsv/5b0c621cd1f10a00123b8914). Just click "Clone and edit this document" at the bottom of the page, and sign up/in.

You can also use equivalent libraries in other platforms like Python rather than Node.js.

---

### PHP method

You can also accomplish this using PHP, since you're already using it on your web server. We use two pages, one to input the request URLs and use the results, and one to execute the HTTP GET requests. Here's some working code:

### IMPORTANT NOTE

If you expose these PHP pages to the internet, anyone can make HTTP requests to any URL using your web-server. This is **DANGEROUS**, and I recommend strongly against it. You need to add checks to ensure that your code is not used maliciously. This doesn't apply if the code is only being used by you, and it is absolutely not accessible over the internet. [Security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) is not good enough!

**compareindex.php**

```
<?php
    $sendLoc = "compare.php";
?>

<!-- This part submits the URLs to the compare script to get executed -->
<form action="<?php echo($sendLoc); ?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="URL1" placeholder="Enter URL1">
    <input type="text" name="URL2" placeholder="Enter URL2">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<!-- This part gets the posted values back from the compare script to be processed in JavaScript -->
<script>
    var finalURL1 = "<?php echo($_POST['fURL1']); ?>"; // PHP will fill these variables if we just requested a comparison
    var finalURL2 = "<?php echo($_POST['fURL2']); ?>";

    document.write(finalURL1); //Just an example, displaying the returned values and if they're equal
    document.write("<br>");
    document.write(finalURL2);
    document.write("<br>");
    if(finalURL1 && finalURL2){
        document.write("Equal: " + (finalURL1==finalURL2));
    }
</script>
```

**compare.php**

```
<?php
    $returnLoc = "compareindex.php";
?>

<!-- This part gets the URL values posted and determines the final URLs (after redirect) -->
<?php
    function getRedirectURL($URL) {
        $ch = curl_init(); //Create curl resource 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL); //Set starting url 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //Return the transfer as a string 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); //Follow redirects
        curl_exec($ch); //Execute request to get final url, discard data
        $fURL = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL); //Get final url
        curl_close($ch); //Close curl resource to free up system resources 
        return $fURL; //Return final url
    }

    $URL1 = $_POST['URL1'];
    $URL2 = $_POST['URL2'];

    $returnValues['fURL1'] = getRedirectURL($URL1);
    $returnValues['fURL2'] = getRedirectURL($URL2);
?>

<!-- This part takes the final URLs and posts them back to the original page -->
<form id="redirForm" action="<?php echo($returnLoc); ?>" method="post">
<?php
    foreach ($returnValues as $a => $b) { //Makes a HTML form input for each return value
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="'.htmlentities($a).'" value="'.htmlentities($b).'">';
    }
?>
</form>
<script>
    document.getElementById('redirForm').submit(); //Submit the form automatically
</script>
```

You type your URLs in the input boxes, and then when you press submit, `compareindex.php` makes a POST request to `compare.php`. `compare.php` then makes GET requests for the two URLs posted, and then makes a POST request back to `compareindex.php` with the redirect URLs, where the values are displayed.

[image: Image of the result]

Comment: I suspected iframes might have that issue from other posts on here. This code does exactly what I'm looking for, however, I'm new to Node.js and I can't figure out how to run this on my website. I have node downloaded already and it works when it's a .js file, however my website is .php and is causing an error. Could you explain how to incorporate this into my website or point me in the right direction for how to go about it.